# Python Application not responding

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to create a simple application which would understand if our eyes are closed or not. First, I need data to use for teaching, before that I wanted to test if I could get the values printed (See below code). When I press the key "q", frame freezes and expects me to put another input. After that, Either I press keys "q" or "w", the application starts not responding.

I have 3 warnings which like below in PyCharm IDE :

```
Name "left_eye_distance" can be undefined
Name "right_eye_distance" can be undefined
Name "nose_distance" can be undefined
```

I don't know if it is not responding because of these errors, but I couldn't fix it. Is there a problem with my code?

```
import cv2
import dlib

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()  # face detector
model = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")  # face points

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # get video capture from camera

f = open("dataset.csv", "r+")


# Mid-point of eye pupil covers
def mid(p1, p2):
    return int((p1[0] + p2[0]) / 2), int((p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2)


# Get Right Eye Coordinates
def getRightEye():
    p1_right, p2_right = points_list[37], points_list[38]  # upper eye points
    p3_right, p4_right = points_list[40], points_list[41]  # lower eye points

    # put circles in those points
    cv2.circle(frame, (p1_right[0], p1_right[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p2_right[0], p2_right[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p3_right[0], p3_right[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p4_right[0], p4_right[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # get mid-point of both upper eye and lower eye
    po_right = mid(p1_right, p2_right)
    po_bottom_right = mid(p3_right, p4_right)

    # create circles for mid-points
    cv2.circle(frame, (po_right[0], po_right[1]), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (po_bottom_right[0], po_bottom_right[1]), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    return po_bottom_right[1] - po_right[1]


# Get Left Eye Coordinates
def getLeftEye():
    p1_left, p2_left = points_list[43], points_list[44]  # upper eye points
    p3_left, p4_left = points_list[47], points_list[46]  # lower eye points

    # put circles in those points
    cv2.circle(frame, (p1_left[0], p1_left[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p2_left[0], p2_left[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p3_left[0], p3_left[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (p4_left[0], p4_left[1]), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    # get mid-point of both upper eye and lower eye
    po_left = mid(p1_left, p2_left)
    po_bottom_left = mid(p3_left, p4_left)

    # create circles for mid-points
    cv2.circle(frame, (po_left[0], po_left[1]), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)
    cv2.circle(frame, (po_bottom_left[0], po_bottom_left[1]), 3, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    return po_bottom_left[1] - po_left[1]


# Get Nose Distance
def getNose():
    return points_list[30][1] - points_list[27][1]


# Infinite loop
while True:

    _, frame = cap.read()  # read the capture
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert the captured frame to gray

    faces = detector(gray)  # get each detected faces in the frame

    for face in faces:  # for each face detected
        points = model(gray, face)  # get points in current face
        points_list = [(p.x, p.y) for p in points.parts()]  # put these face point shapes in a list both x,y coordinates

        # Get Eye Coordinates
        left_eye_distance = getLeftEye()
        right_eye_distance = getRightEye()
        nose_distance = getNose()

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)  # show the frame on the screen

    # key press loop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff == ord("q"):
        result = input(" Enter input : ")

        if result == "q":
            break

        elif result == "w":
            left = input(" Input data for left eye : ")
            right = input(" Input data for right eye : ")
            print(f" Left Eye : {left_eye_distance} "
                  f"Right Eye : {right_eye_distance}, "
                  f"Nose : {nose_distance}\n")

cap.release()  # capture ended
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # all windows closed
```

Comment: "Is there a problem with my code?" -- the answer appears to be "yes". Do you understand the warnings? Fixing those issues is a natural place to start your debugging.

Comment: What is the point of the `input` statements?  You never use the values of `left` and `right` anywhere.

Comment: That `if cv2.waitKey` statement says "if the user pressed the 'q', key, go ask the user for input".  To quit, you would need to press `q`, `q`, enter.  I don't think that's what you wanted.

Comment: @TimRoberts I will use them for later for creating data in .csv file. This is not the exact code I would want, it's just testing printing if I could get the data correctly.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I can simply create an else condition for cv2.waitKey() and would be expecting 'w'. But the problem starts after I press the second input, which is either 'q' or 'w'.

Comment: @JohnColeman I get your point, but I couldn't fix the warnings no way. What does it mean by "undefined" ? I defined those variables in for loop.

Comment: No, the point is you need to SAVE the result of waitKey and check THAT value for either 'q' or 'w'.  You don't need to require a second input for the command.

Comment: You also need to remember that there is a distinct possibility that the face detector won't find anything.  You aren't handling the failure case right now.